# Expression must be a list type: Set<Id>

Tags: apex

```
public Map<Id, Integer> gettotalLead(){
     Map<ID, Integer> leadCount = new Map<ID, Integer>();
      integer count=0;
     for(integer i=0;i<userID.size();i++){
      for(Lead l  : leadList){
          if(Lead.OwnerId = userID[i])
        count = count++;
        }  
        leadcount.put(userid[i], count);
     }
     return leadCount;
   }
```

Comment: Please give us which line number the error is thrown. Did you declared leadList or userID as a Set instead of List?

Comment: Can you please add some more details about what you are trying to accomplish, and what is not working properly? Thanks.

Comment: what is `userID`?  what is `leadList`?

Comment: Does this code even work?  what errors are you getting?  It cannot work as it is.

Comment: for line 6 in above code. I am a fresher and trying to build a report  based on user so i want to fetch the ids from my list of users... here userId is a SET type

Answer (score 3):

Please change this line `if(Lead.OwnerId = userID[i])`  to  `if(l.OwnerId == userID[i])` which is giving the error.

Also advice you to follow proper naming convention.

**Update**

Since you are using `Set<Id>` for `userId` I have updated the code to make it compile. Also changed variable `userId` to `userIdSet` for better understanding.

```
public Map<Id, Integer> getTotalLead(){
 Map<ID, Integer> mapLeadCount = new Map<ID, Integer>();
  integer count=0;
 for(Id idObj:userIDSet){
      for(Lead l  : leadList) {
          if(userIDSet.contains(l.OwnerId))
            count = count++;
      }  
      mapLeadCount.put(idObj, count);
 }
 return mapLeadCount;
}
}
```

Refer documentation about [Set Class](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/apex_methods_system_set.htm) and [List or Set Iteration for Loops](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/langCon_apex_loops_for_lists.htm) for more knowledge.

Comment: Still its throwing the same error

Comment: @vipulmittal please check my updated answer and close this question